# how create an vocal assistant with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning

I would like to know if creating an ai that interprets the words seems feasible for a beginner

For example currently I have to say "give weather" and it gives me the weather, but if I say give the weather please it won't.

I don't realize how difficult my ambitions are

So, if you have already done or you know yourselves in IA (or not) and you have any advice, I will be grateful to you.

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is a voice assistant, if I understood correctly. Creating a real AI is possible for a beginner, but it would be smart to stick with event driven programming.

Anyways, if you are willing to make an assistant, this should help you get started on windows:

```
import speech_recognition as sr 
import pyttsx3

r = sr.Recognizer()                  #
engine = pyttsx3.init()              #
engine.setProperty('rate', 145)      #
                                     #  The Main Part (Listens to the voice)
def speak(audio):                    #
    engine.say(audio)                #
    engine.runAndWait()              #

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say Something:  ")
    audio = r.listen(source)         #Starts listening

    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio).lower()
        print('You said : {}'.format(text))       #Tries to understand what you said

    except:
        print('Sorry I could not recognize your voice')
```

This should help you have a rough layout, some of the modules are different on other operating systems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i did something like that 
but I would like to implement an ia, which would analyze my sentences (even basic),
I inquired and saw some software like dialogflow, would like the ia can understand the difference between "give the meteo" and "don't give the meteo" (its just an example)

Comment: You could add a custom variable, containing negatives like don't, isn't, or not and then every time it detects them it will not do it.

Comment: Ok thanks, so do you think its not a good idea to implement an IA for this? (ty for your answers)

Comment: An AI would be cool, there is actually a YouTube series for something like this, but they use machine learning and its a little too complicated for a beginner. If you want to give it a try then you will need to do a little more research. I have done something like this, but it is not an AI, it is just event driven bot. I think an AI would be my final version. If you want to check it out you are more then welcome to: [link](https://github.com/Khutord435/Multitool) It it still in development and so far I only tested it in Linux. You are more then welcome to do an AI version.

Comment: thanks, i'm checking your assistant and i think i will take some informations about it :)

Comment: It has not been updated in some time, so some parts may not work